# Type Mismatch 13 error 13 on setting array value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure what's going on, I though it'd be a simple code.

Basically, I'm just creating an array list based whether or not a cell value is True. But I'm getting the error when setting the array to the cell value. Did I miss something?

```
Sub test()
    Dim chklst() As String
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Select")
        For i = 1 To 10
            If .Cells(14 + i, 12).Value = "True" Then
                chklst() = .Cells(14 + i, 13).Value 'This is where the error shows up
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

When adding a watch, it found that  `.Cells(14 + i, 13).Value` is a Variant/String. Changing the variable to Variant doesn't work. Changing .Value to .Text doesn't work either.. Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not declared the size of the array. Without declaring the size there is no where to put anything.

```
Sub test()

    With Worksheets("Select")

        Dim chklst() As String
        ReDim chklst(1 To Application.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(15, 12), .Cells(24, 12)), "True"))


        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 10
            If .Cells(14 + i, 12).Value = "True" Then
                chklst(i) = .Cells(14 + i, 13).Value 'This is where the error shows up
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, so that's why just adding chklst(i) just says subscript out of range. I was comparing it on my other array list code and I didn't have to declare the size at all and it was working without issues, so not sure why I have to declare it this time. But yeah, got it working now.

Comment: @Basher look closer, because accessing an uninitialized array subscript throws error 9 *as per language specifications*, and those aren't changing between debugging sessions.